# How to make relationship between Amazon Cognito and other microservice?

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am new to AWS and making some large application with microservice architecture. I am using Cognito user + identity pools for authorization. Organizations have branches, branches have positions, e.g Project Manager, Financial Manager, and a user belong to one of these branches and positions. Users are stored in the Cognito User Pool. I've EC2 and RDS for organization microservice and I'm going to use AWS API gateway with IAM Role-Based Access Control to communicate between microservices but how can I make a relationship between the organization and user microservices?

I was going to use Cognito custom attributes, e.g `custom:branch=branchId` but if I needed to get the users of this branch that would be impossible. From Cognito docs:

> Custom attributes are not searchable.

Should I use DynamoDB table, for relation `cognito_user_id | branch_id`, or what's the better approach?

How to get single branch users, how to get single organization users and where to write this code ? AWS lambda with DynamoDB ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no restriction to add table on RDS at organization micro-service, I will say do not use dynamodb as it is an extra component and your system supports relational better than NoSQL. Besides, one more prerequisite for dynamodb is one must be aware of data access pattern.

Create Organizations and Branchs table having one-to-many relation as seperate micro-service. User will be assigned to Branch.

You should write those shared logic to lambda as a service and that lambda will be called by both org and user services. I know that will cost extra integration effort. However, it is far better than adding new service like dynamodb.

Comment: What do you mean user will be assigned to branch ? As u said, I've one-to-many relation with organization and branchs but how assign users to branch?  1. add a custom attribute in Cognito and write branchId to it  2. Create user_branch table in organization RDS ?